# Using jQuery crossdomain (JSONP) to log in - GET might be an issue

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp

I'm building a bookmarking utility that will add a button to another website, and send data back when the button is clicked. If a user is logged in to my service, they get an "ok", otherwise a prompt to log in or register.

So far the initial communication is ok using a jQuery AJAX request and JSONP as the datatype. I'm able to send through the initial data to the server, and have it reply with a form.

Edit: Rewrite to clarify the question:

If I'm sending a login using JSONP (which uses GET), would using https be pointless as the username and password would be in the url?

Comment: GET is not inherently more insecure than POST, in practice GET-requests are more likely to get logged in full "by mistake". But really, neither is more secure than the other... that is to say, both are insecure in the sense that both can be easily intercepted as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS crypts everything, including HTTPS header (this include the *URL*). So, using HTTPS  would actually be a good thing.